# WebGL: Switch between Shaders

Tags: webgl, shader

i wrote a tiny function to switch between shaders, but unfortunatelly it doesn't work.
I create the shaders and return them as shader objects.

1. program = gl.createProgram(vs, fs, "VertexPosition", "TextureCoord", "VertexNormal");
2. depthprogram = gl.createProgram(vs, fs, "VertexPosition", false, false);

I use the switch function in my update function which consists of :

```
    function Update(){ 
            gl.switchProgram(program);
            gl.Draw(Teapot, cam);
    };
```

All buffers of the model are bind in the draw function, (parameters: the model, camera position)

```
    this.switchProgram = function(program){

    if (this.program !== program){
        this.lastprogram = this.program;
        this.program = program;
        gl.useProgram(this.program);

    };

};
```

Here is the resulting error: WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawElements: attribs not setup correctly 
If i comment all works fine, but i'm unable to switch :(

```
depthprogram = gl.createProgram(vs, fs, "VertexPosition", false, false);
gl.switchProgram(program);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do both shaders use same attributes?
As far as  I could conclude from your code, first shader uses:

```
attribute vertexPos;
attribute vertexNormal;
attribute textureCoord;
```

while second uses only

```
attribute vertexPos;
```

If you try to send attribute that isn't being used in vertex shader of the program, or you don't send attribute that vertex shader requests, then you'll get the warning.
I would say that you don't send vertexNormal and textureCoord for the first shader, although shader needs them.

Hope this helps.